# CodeIgniter MVC Model Logic

Tags: model-view-controller, oop, codeigniter, model

I have programmed in Rails, Django, Zend, and CakePHP.  Also, Wordpress and Drupal.

Now, I am "catching up to speed" in as fairly large application in CodeIgniter.

Typically, my experience with MVC frameworks, has led me to believe that Models represent business logic in reference to actual database tables.  In the CodeIgniter docs and in the code base I'm dissecting I see models created that represent something as vague as a page.  A lot of the business logic is written directly into those models and they incorporate other actual data models.  I'm not sure this is ideal and following MVC.

Should models be created beyond data models?

Also, lets say I have a data model representing a user (`user` table in DB).  In that user table there is a column called `gender` of the type enum('male', 'female').  Now I want to populate a dropdown with the gender options from the enum column.

Where is it most appropriate to put this logic?

The user model is an object used to represent a single user or row in the db... right?  So it doesn't seem fitting to include a function in the user model/class called "get_gender_options", because, while the function is related to the user table, it is NOT relevant to a single user object.  In Zend this kind of logic could be built into the form object itself.

There is not "right" answer, just one we can consider the most appropriate...

Answer (score 0):

I would probably just put the "get_gender_options" in the model, rather than sticking it in the view for the form. To keep it DRY but not put it in the model, I would create a helper to hold this.